# Certain Wi-Fi network not available on Motorola Milestone with Cyanogenmod

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, settings, factory-reset, motorola-milestone

I have a Motorola Milestone with Cyanogenmod 7.2.0. Phone is working without any problems.

I was using this phone with my own Wi-Fi network. Something happened, and after that I'm not able to connect to Wi-Fi.

The Wi-Fi router should be fine (we use it with another Android phone and two notebooks without any problem). I made factory reset that didn't solve the problem (after factory reset, I started to use it with different account, so it didn't restore the Wi-Fi settings).

The phone is able to search for Wi-Fi hotspots (it finds a neighbor's Wi-Fi), but it doesn't list my own Wi-Fi network.

I can't figure out the reason, I think it is not hardware related. Maybe I disabled to connect to this Wi-Fi accidentally, I don't know.

Is there a way to check the setting for a certain Wi-Fi, or at least can I reset full Wi-Fi settings?

Comment: Try changing channel or mode.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1. If your WLAN is running in 2.4GHz mode you should chekc the used channel. Not all channels are allowed in all countries - especiall in the US the channels higher than 13 are AFAIK forbidden. Therefore some devices do not even scan the frequencies that belong to those channels. What frequencies/channels are used is specified by the driver/firmware - therefore using CM7 my be the problem. Try to cache your WLAN access point config to use a lower WLAN chennel.
2. Your WLAN is running in 5GHz mode only. Only devices with 5GHz capable WLAN hardware can use a WLAn that is operating in 5GHz only mode. Unfortunately the number of smartphones that are 5GHz capable is very short. Therefore you should check your WLAN access point config if it is in 5GHz only mode and if so change it to dual frequency mode 2.4GHz + 5Ghz running at the same time.

Comment: I'm sure that not this is my problem. See edit section.

Comment: Some WiFi access point select the channel automatically based on the surrounding WLANs. Therefore a wrong channel would be still possible.